# how to extend base class functionality

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have a class:

```
public class Person {
    public string FirstName = "";
    public string LastName = "";
}
```

and a derived class:

```
public class HRPerson : Person {
    public string GetSomething() {
      //calculate something
    }
}
```

Essentilly, I'm wanting to extend the functionality of the base class. The use looks like this, where `GetAllPerson` returns `List<Person>`.

```
class Program
{
     static List<HRPerson> GetAllHRPerson()
     {
         List<HRPerson> HRPersonList = new List<HRPerson>();
         foreach (Person person in GetAllPerson)
         {
             HRPersonList.Add(person);
         }
         return HRPersonList;
     }
}
```

It doesn't compile, saying that there is no overload for the parameter, and when I try to cast person to `HRPerson`, I get the runtime error "unable to cast object of type `Person` to type `HRPerson`" error.

How do I go about adding additional functionality like this?

Comment: Can you provide more information what exactly you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like your `GetAllPerson` is returning some non-HR people...

Assuming that's the case and you just want to filter those out, it's easiest to use LINQ's [`OfType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) method:

```
static List<HRPerson> GetAllHRPerson()
{
    return GetAllPerson().OfType<HRPerson>().ToList();
}
```

(Side note: please avoid public fields like this, other than for constants. Fields should be an implementation detail, not part of your public API.)

Of course if none of your `Person` instances are actually instances of `HRPerson`, that's not going to help you. You can't change the type of an instance once it's been created. It's not really clear what your situation is - if this answer doesn't help you, please provide more details.

EDIT: I'm still not really sure that you want an extension method, but if you do, it would be something like:

```
public static class PersonExtensions
{
    public static string GetSomething(this Person person)
    {
        // Do something with the given Person
    }
}
```

You can then call that on any `Person` as if it were an instance method:

```
Person person = ...;
string something = person.GetSomething();
```

But this is *not* polymorphic - it's not that you're changing anything about the `Person` object, which your description still makes it sound like you really want to do...

Comment: GetAllPerson returns a list of Person only.

Comment: @Tremors101: Well then how did you expect it to work? If none of the references actually refers to an `HRPerson`, how did you expect one to be created?

Comment: This is a scaled down example.  The idea is that different client code may get different versions of the Person class.  e.g. HRPerson.GetFullName might return 'LName, FName', whereas CCPerson.GetFullName might return 'FName LName', and I don't have any control over the Person class, and Person.GetFullName doesn't exist

Comment: Yup, I get that it doesn't work, and I'm looking for the right way to accomplish this.  Perhaps inheriting isn't the right path.

Comment: @Tremors101: No, it sounds like you *might* want an extension method instead. But fundamentally you haven't really given us enough information. Why did you *think* you should use inheritance here?

Comment: I thought I needed inheritance here so that when client code that is dealing with HR persons get's a list of type person, they can cast it to HRPerson and get the correct implementation of HRPerson.GetSomething.  Some other client code might implement a derived class of OtherDepartmentPerson:Person and return a different implementation of GetSomething.  The catch seems to be that Person doesn't implement GetSomething, so I can't just override it.

Comment: @Tremors101: But you've said that the object *isn't* an instance of `HRPerson`. What did you expect to be creating an instance of `HRPerson`?

Comment: No, the code in the example illustrates what I'm trying to do, although it's illegal.  I guess you could say that I'm trying to add functionality to Person by deriving Person to HRPerson.  The problem is that my datasource only returns Person, and I want to cast to any number of derived classes.  Not allowed.  However, I do like your idea of using an extension method, and I implemented that nicely.  How do I mark that as a good answer?

Comment: @Tremors101: Well it still doesn't *really* sound like that's the way to go, but I'll add a bit to my answer to explain it - you can then click on the tickbox under the answer score to accept it. The problem is that nothing can change the actual type of an object after construction, and that's what it sounds like you're *really* trying to do.

Comment: I think you're right Jon.  I was hoping for an answer that would guide me towards a standard practice, but this will do.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments to Jon Skeet's answer, is this what you are looking for:

Create a subclass of Person, for example, NamedPerson. Give NamedPerson a method GetFullName, which returns the full name of the Person.

Then create a subclass HRPerson from NamedPerson, and override GetFullName to return the name in a slightly different format. CCPerson would also be subclassed from NamedPerson.

You have no control over Person, but you have full control over NamedPerson. Then what you want is a list of NamedPersons, not of HRPersons. This list could contain bare NamedPersons, or HRPersons, or CCPersons, but all objects on the list would be NamedPersons or subclasses of it, so they would all have GetFullName.

Comment: So when I get a list of Person from my dataprovider, how do I cast them to be NamedPerson?  By subclass, do you mean:  Class NamedPerson:Person{}

Comment: If you are getting Person from somewhere, and have no control over it, and want to add subclasses with base class methods, then one thing you can do is create NamedPerson which has a Person as a member. It's not a subclass -- it's a new base class which has a Person inside it. Then expose NamedPerson.GetFullName, and make all your subclasses from NamedPerson.